# How to parse a string in .xsl file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an attribute Host name, the value of which I want to match with the format a.b.c.com, and then generate the key value as ANAME:a. How can this be done in xsl stylesheet xml version 1.0?

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value "a" from a string "a.b.c.com" using [`substring-before()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/CR-xpath-functions-20051103/#func-substring-before).

Assuming that you have selected the value "a.b.c.com" and have assigned to a variable called `$host`:

```
concat('ANAME:', substring-before($host, '.'))
```

Comment: And is their any function to verify that the hostname value is in the format of a.b.c.com?

Comment: with XPath 2.0 and greater, you have access to functions that use regex, so you can use `matches()` or `replace()`

Comment: is the subdomain static (i.e. `b.c.com`), or you just want to ensure that there are that many components to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70301645/how-to-match-an-attributes-format-to-a-b-c-com-in-xsl-stylesheet-xml-version