# How to match an attribute's format to "a.b.c.com" in .xsl stylesheet xml version 1.0?

Tags: xml, string, xslt, match

I need to perform some action based on the condition that host name is in the format : a.b.c.com,( example : she01-qlv.abc.jio.com). Is their any inbuilt function to match this format?

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when I answered it. Otherwise my answer would not make sense to anyone else reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no regex support in XSLT 1.0. If you want something relatively simple, you could test that the input contains 3 periods using:

```
translate($host, translate($host, '.', ''), '') = '...'
```

and that it ends with `.com` using:

```
substring($host, string-length($host)-3) = '.com'
```

However this will also pass an input like `abc...com`.

Comment: You can see it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVaq

Comment: How would I know? You did not post a [mcve].

Comment: To combine the conditions use the `and` operator. I am not sure what you mean by "similar working example ...". You have the basic principles, you should be able to apply them to your situation.